# All employees have permission, but they get the "ask for permission" message

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

For multiple SharePoint Online subsites that I have created, I'm experiencing unusual behavior. No one who has not already visited the sites can gain access, even though "All employees" have Read access. Others, who have viewed pages in the past, find it to perform normally.

On another special-purpose subsite, a **site owner** is told she lacks permissions when she clicks a link (which is just that, a link to a file in a Quick Links web part). If she opens the Document Library the file is in, she can download it from there, but the link doesn't work--again, for one of the owners of the site.

We have tested in both Google Chrome (latest) and Internet Explorer 11. These are the only corporate-approved browsers at this time.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar issue, and the root cause was that someone has removed 'Everyone' read access from the root site, that causes similar issues in SPO to the one you described.

Comment: In this case, it was a configuration change made above my level. (I am site owner, but not a SharePoint administrator.) The administrators fixed the problem a couple of days later.